# How to dynamically center an image that repeats on the x-axis with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a background image that is 1500px in width and repeats on the x-axis. I would like to dynamically center this image no matter the user's viewport width so that the image's center is always in the middle of the screen?

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need JavaScript for this, CSS will (or should) do just fine:

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

That line will ensure that the image is always centered in the element, and that it repeats starting from the center of that element. [More info on background-position here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

Comment: Doing it this way will also repeat on the y axis. Make sure you also use `background-repeat: repeat-x;` to make sure it only repeats on the x axis.

Comment: I assumed he was already using that because he said it repeated along the x axis, but excellent point.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question here, but I believe you can do this with just CSS.

```
.container {
  background: url('path/to/image') repeat-x 50% 0;
}
```

Is that what you had in mind?